# How to extract words between two non characters patterns?

Tags: bash, shell

I was wondering how to extract all the words between these two patterns: `****_` and `_****`. The underscore means whitespace.

So far I have done:

```
awk '/^**** / {flag=1;next} / ****$/{flag=0} flag {print}'
```

**Part of the file**

```
.
.
.
**** Hoja de vida ****
Nombre                
Nombre en citaciones 
Nacionalidad         
**** Formación Académica ****
.
.
.
```

Comment: `*` is tricky because it has special meaning in regexes (and shell pattern matching).  In general you will need to escape characters like this with a backslash: `\*`

Comment: What does "non characters patterns" mean? `'*'` and `' '` are characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main issue with your answer. First is not escaping the meta-character `*`. Second *was* not showing your sample input file initially. `:)`

Since you would like to grab words between a pattern, you can do:

```
awk 'gsub(/\*\*\*\*/,"")==2 && $1=$1' file
```

`gsub` function returns the number of substitutions made. Since we are interested in lines that are enclosed between `****` we put a check of 2. `$1=$1` is to ensure there are no leading and trailing spaces in your output.

Answer (score 3):

The following should do. Note that `*` needs to be escaped. Note that this solution is inclusive of the start and end pattern

```
awk '/^\*\*\*\* /,/ \*\*\*\*$/'  file
```

If you need the start and end patterns excluded

```
awk '/^\*\*\*\* /,/ \*\*\*\*$/{if ($0 !~ /^\*\*\*\* | \*\*\*\*$/)print}' file
```

or slightly more terse with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed -n '/^\*\*\*\* /,/ \*\*\*\*$/{/^\*\*\*\* \| \*\*\*\*$/!p}' file
```

Comment: Thanks, but it print with the symbols : ( and I would like to print only the words

Comment: @Alejandro, not sure what you mean but take a look at the edit

Comment: @JS웃 Thanks for your reply, but it print me all the document : (

Comment: @JS웃 I checked through dos2unix and I'm still getting the same the result : (

Comment: @JS웃 Ok, I have posted part of the file : )

Comment: @JS웃, please post that as a separate answer

Comment: @JS웃, your solution is completely different than mine. I insist you post your separately ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting on 4* enclosed with optional white space:

```
echo '**** Hoja de vida ****' | awk -F' *\\*\\*\\*\\* *' '{print $2}'
Hoja de vida
```